# Sympy.Rational doesn't work correctly with fractions like 1/3

Tags: python, sympy

I have this code:

```
import sympy as smp
a = smp.Rational(1/3)
print('1/3: ', a)
a = smp.Rational(1/6)
print('1/6: ', a)
a = smp.Rational(1/2)
print('1/2: ', a)
a = smp.Rational(1/4)
print('1/4: ', a)
```

and this result:

```
1/3:  6004799503160661/18014398509481984
1/6:  6004799503160661/36028797018963968
1/2:  1/2
1/4:  1/4
```

sympy doesn't work correctly with different fractions like 1/3, 1/5, 1/6, etс.
How can i solve this problem?

[There is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE7ZD.png)

Comment: I thought it expected `smp.Rational(1,3)`

Comment: what @hpaulj said... see the docs https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.numbers.Rational ...you are asking it to represent the float `0.3333333333333333` as a fraction, instead of `1/3`

Comment: Oh, thank you, it was so easy that now I'm confused, thank you

Comment: The 1/2 and 1/4 misled you.  Those "work" because the resulting floats, expressible as 0.5 and 0.25 are "exact", with powers of two in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `1/3`, that immediately performs the division. So

```
sympy.Rational(1/3)
```

is the same as

```
sympy.Rational(6004799503160661/18014398509481984)
```

because in Python,

```
1/3 == 6004799503160661/18014398509481984
```

You must pass the numerator and denominator to the Rational factory:

```
sympy.Rational(1, 3)
```

Comment: `sympy.Rational('1/3')` should also work.